# How to make the code continue the process if the file upload section is empty PHP MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with 1 part of upload section, how to make the code continue the process if the upload section is empty? I already make the code, but everytime i skip the file button, it show echo 'ERROR: Ekstensi file tidak di izinkan!'

Here is my code:

**insert_form**

```
<form name="pegawai" action="insert-proses.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <table width="700px" align="left" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <td><b>NOKOM</b></td>
  <td><b>:</b></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="nokom" size="40" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><b>NIP</b></td>
  <td><b>:</b></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="nip" size="40" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><b>Nama</b></td>
  <td><b>:</b></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="nama" size="40" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><b>Foto</b></td>
  <td><b>:</b></td>
  <td><input name="file" type="file" id="file" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><hr/><input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

insert-proses

```
<?php session_start();
include "config.php";

if(ISSET($_SESSION['superadmin'])) {
    if($_POST['upload']) {
        $nokom      = $_POST['nokom'];      
        $nip        = $_POST['nip'];
        $nama       = $_POST['nama']; 

        // Proses upload file
        $allowed_ext  = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
        $file_name    = $_FILES['file']['name']; // Nama File
        $file_ext     = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name))); // Merubah nama file
        $file_size    = $_FILES['file']['size']; // Size File
        $file_tmp     = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // Temp File

        // Proses pengecekan upload file
        if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === true) {
            if($file_size < 5220350) // Max upload file 5 MB / 1MB = 1044070 {
                $lokasi = 'files/'.$nama.'.'.$file_ext;
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $lokasi);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO pegawai (nokom,nip,nama,fileext,filegambar)
          VALUES('$nokom','$nip','$nama','$file_ext','$lokasi')";

            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "<script>alert('Insert data berhasil! Klik ok untuk melanjutkan');location.replace('pegawai-list.php')</script>";
            } 
            else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        } else
            {
                echo '<div class="error">ERROR: Besar ukuran file (file size) maksimal 1 Mb!</div>';
            }
    } else
        {
            echo '<div class="error">ERROR: Ekstensi file tidak di izinkan!</div>';
        }
} 
} else
      {
          echo '<script>alert("Anda bukan Superadmin! Silahkan login menjadi Superadminterlebih dahulu");location.replace("index.php")</script>';
      }
?>
```

Any help will be so thankful. Thanks

Comment: Your braces aren't matched properly. You have two `}` for the first `if`

Comment: There's no `name="upload"` in your form, so `if($_POST['upload'])` should always fail.

Comment: @Barmar ouch, sorry sir. i forget copy the upload button to insert above.

Answer (score 0):

Jump over the complete upload part if there is no file uploaded, or better, run the upload part in your script only IF a file is uploaded:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']) && is_array($_FILES['file'])) {
    // your code to upload and check the file
}
```